# How can I use Ckfinder with Ckeditor?

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

I was used Ckeditor in my project. It was worked well. I can put picture in texts but with an url. I know that,if I want upload an picture from my pc, I must used CKfinder.
How can I use Ckfinder with Ckeditor?

I use this code to call CKeditor:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String StrScript = "CKEDITOR.replace( '" + TextBox1.ClientID + "',{toolbar : 'Full'});";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Ck-Js/ckeditor", StrScript, true);

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it takes nearly 5 minutes to complete setup:

1. Download CKEditor and CKFinder.
2. Put extracted code of both in one folder inside xampp as below.
3. Create index file (index.html) which will be containing the editor as below code.

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <h1>CKEditor CKFinder Integration using PHP</h1>
       <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
       filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
       filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
       filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
       filebrowserUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
       filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
       filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
   });
   CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '../' );
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

so your folder structure will be something like this:

```
htdocs
|_integrated
    |_ckeditor
    |   |_config.js
    |   |_...
    |_ckfinder
    |   |_config.php
    |   |_...
    |_uploads
    |_index.html
```

1. Now open file config.php inside ckfinder & make following changes:

   ```
   function CheckAuthentication() {
       return true;
   }
   $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/integrated/uploads/';
   $enabled = true;
   $config['SecureImageUploads'] = false;
   $config['ChmodFolders'] = 0777 ;
   ```
2. Now open url `http://localhost/integrated/` and try uploading image.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want use CKFinder and CKEditor, try this :

- Documentation : http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP/CKEditor_Integration
- http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP/FCKeditor_Integration
- En Francais : http://creer-un-site.fr/integration-du-formulaire-d-upload-ckfinder-a-l-editeur-ckeditor-202.php

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having problems integrating CKFinder with CKEditor, try using KCFinder (http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/) instead.

It has all the same functions as CKFinder, but its free, open source, and much easier to install and setup. (Personally, I was never able to get CKFinder installed properly....)

The installation instructions for KCFinder are here: 
http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/install

And the integration instructions are here:
http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/integrate

Answer (score 1):

1. https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/download/
2. download [ckfinder](https://ckeditor.com/ckfinder/download/) place it both in single place then

   ```
   <textarea class="ckeditor" id="editor1"></textarea>
   ```

   place this code in footer.php or direct on page also

   ```
   CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
       filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'https://example.com/admin/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
       filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: 'https://example.com/admin/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
       filebrowserUploadUrl: 'https://example.com/admin/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
       filebrowserImageUploadUrl: 'https://example.com/admin/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
   });
   ```

   in `ckfinder/config.php` file open and make some change

   ```
   $config['authentication'] = function () {
     return true;
   };

   $config['backends'][] = array(
     'name'         => 'default',
     'adapter'      => 'local',
     'baseUrl'      => 'https://example.com/admin/ckfinder/userfiles/',
     //  'root'         => '', // Can be used to explicitly set the CKFinder user files directory.
     'chmodFiles'   => 0777,
     'chmodFolders' => 0755,
     'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
   );
   ```

That's it, it work for me.
If this is helpful for you please rate us me